# Is the set of linear transformations without unit norm eigenvalues dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $E$ be a Banach space and
$$H_p=\{f\in\mathcal L(E): f(v)=\lambda v\ (v \neq 0)\implies |\lambda|\neq 1\}$$
be the set of linear operators which don't have an eigenvalue with norm $1$. Is $H_p$ dense in $\mathcal L(E)$?

This is false if we consider the set of hyperbolic transformations
$$H=\{f\in\mathcal L(E):\lambda \in \sigma(f)\implies |\lambda|\neq 1\}$$
as José Alves shows in [these lecture notes](https://www.fc.up.pt/pessoas/jfalves/pub/senegal.pdf), on example 5.3.

The space $H_p$ feels much bigger than $H$, plus the proof that the hyperbolic matrices in a finite dimensional space are dense by perturbing the eigenvalues makes me think that this is true.

Comment: Don't you want that "$f(v)=\lambda v\ (\forall v\in E)\implies |\lambda|\neq 1$" to be "$(\exists v\in E \text{,}  v \ne 0 \text{ and } f(v)=\lambda v) \implies |\lambda|\neq 1$"?

Comment: From the context I gather that the assumption means $\lambda\in\sigma_p(f)\implies |\lambda|\neq 1.$